# Reloading table not working as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

Sorry for the poor title, I genuinely don't know how to title this question, but essentially what I am trying to do is, after everything has loaded on the page, I want to change a drop-down list selection and reload the table data, I have the following code:

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jobs")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("body").data("Jobs.Index", new Jobs.Index({
            detailsUrl: '@Url.Action("Details")',
            applyUrl: '@Url.Action("Apply")',
            keyword: '@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(keyword))',
            showMaxResultsByDefault: @settings.ShowMaxResultsByDefault.ToString().ToLower()
        }));
    });

    $(window).on('load', function () {
        if (showMaxResultsByDefault) {
            $('.koDataTable_pageSizesWrapper select').val('100');
            $('#jobsTable').load();
        }
    });
</script>
```

}

I needed to move the `$(window).on(....` code to one of our existing .ts files, which is called in the `$(function () {...` code, so I added it right at the bottom of the code in the .ts file, but now it's giving the following error when hitting `$('#jobsTable').load();`:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')

By my understanding of the error, the `jobsTable` table does not exist yet, hence the error, but isn't it suppose to be created by now, considering it's in the `$(window).on(...` code? This should be running after everything on the page is loaded.

I can only think that it comes down to the order of events, so I'm missing something, as I thought that running the code in my `$(window).on(...` code, would run after the DOM was created, etc..

Been struggling with this silly thing for a couple of hours, help would be greatly appreciated!

It might be worthy to mention, I am using Knockout Data Tables to populate this table.